# How to pull a Docker image from DockerHub to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions, dockerhub

I wanted to make a CI/CD with a project on Github using GitHub Actions. Used this tutorial:
https://www.blog.labouardy.com/elastic-beanstalk-docker-tips/
But I still do not understand how elastic beanstalk will pull the docker image from the DockerHub.
How should this happen?
And why do we need a Dockerrun.aws.json file and how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different approaches that can be followed. The blogger chose to use the `Dockerrun.aws.json` + `Dockerfile` + zipfile approach. In other words, every time the CircleCI builds, it uploads a zip file containing the `Dockerrun.aws.json` (the  `Dockerfile` is not really needed in this case since he's building the image remotely as well as the rest of the application since he's not mapping anything).

The circleci executes the following steps:

- build image
- push image
- send zip file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk will simply follow the configuration inside the `Dockerrun.aws.json` and update using the tag `${CIRCLE_SHA1}`.

Is the `Dockerrun.aws.json` necessary? No, you can also use a `docker-compose.yml` file.

I suggest you check [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html) on this topic.

EDIT: IMHO it's better to use `docker-compose.yml` since it allows to start the containers locally and make sure they're ok before updating the application remotely

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to ask you one more thing. How can I check that Elastic Beanstalk has made an update following the json file?
I just think that my Elastic Beanstalk just ignores the json file and I just copy the zip of my project into it via S3, and the DockerHUB remains untouched.

Comment: as a test, I'd keep only the Docker.aws.json in the zip file and see how it's going to behave. Anyway you can check in the AWS console what's the current version being used.

Comment: I did it. Only dockerrun.aws.json file in zip -> "Failed to deploy application" in Elastic Beanstalk...

Comment: I found a tutorial and did only what is there, but I still have an error....(((
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBu7Ov3Rt-M&t=1s&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices

Comment: I tried to write in dockerrun.aws.json another image from DockerHub, for example consol/tomcat-8.0
And everything works! But, when I write a pull to my image, it gives an error...
Error : Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0dafdbbfc40f0edd2'. Aborting the operation. -> Failed to deploy application. ->During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

Comment: I probably have a bad project in github:
https://github.com/DANIILNEDOSTUP/my-project

Comment: I checked the project and couldn't see major issues. Can you just try to use `deploy.zip` instead of `deploy.${sha}.zip`? Clean up the remote application first

Comment: Replaced with deployment.zip, but still an error. I think there is something wrong with my docker image, for some reason EB refuses to download it. Could there be a problem with my docker image?
Error: Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log' -> Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed -> [Instance: i-0dafdbbfc40f0edd2] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
I no longer know what could be wrong .....

Answer (score 0):

Like an member said you could use the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html) with complete steps.